# Excel: searching for a value within multiple arrays within cells

Tags: range, excel-formula

I'm trying to set up an error check between two systems and need to compare week numbers in different formats.  One system produces week numbers in a text format e.g "`8-15, 18, 31-32`" and the other produces discrete values. How would I see whether a value e.g 16 fell within a multiple range like the one above?

It's part of a bigger issue where I'm checking a reference number, day, time and week number (e.g `XXX111 Weds 9:00 9`) in one system against the output of another system (e.g `XXX111 Wed 9:00 7:11, 13, 16, 52-63 or XXX111 Thu 9:00 5, 6, 11-16`).  Despite lots of searching I've hit a wall with the bit above so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'd rather not use `VBA` if possible.  Thanks in advance for your wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed:

1. `7:11` should be `7-11`
2. `63` should be `53`
3. A number not part of a range (eg `18`) is not a problem
4. Ranges are in Text format

I hope the following helps or at least is ‘a step in the right direction’:

**A Parse the components**

Eg for `8-15, 18, 31-32`, paste into a cell (say `A1`) and Data > Data Tools - Text to Columns > Delimited > Next > check Comma, Space and Treat consecutive delimiters as one > Next > Select Columns as required > select Text for each > Finish

May be easier to deal with a single column so select data, Copy > Select `A2` > Paste Special > Transpose > OK and Delete contents of `Row1`.

**B Add your search value (`16`) into `B1`**

**C Copy the formula below into `B2` and copy down as required:**

`=AND(B$1>=VALUE(LEFT($A2,SEARCH("-",$A2)-1)),B$1<=VALUE(RIGHT($A2,LEN($A2)-SEARCH("-",$A2)))))`

The result should be `TRUE` where the search value is within or on either bound of the discrete range:

[image: SO13491293 example]

The formula uses the hyphen to ‘recognise’ a discrete range. SEARCH looks for where it is positioned (because there could be one or two characters either side of it). LEFT and RIGHT are for the lower and upper bounds (in the case of RIGHT used in conjunction with LEN to address whether the upper bound is one or two characters). VALUE is required to convert the Text into something that can be equated to the search value. AND is for the process to consider both bounds in determining whether ‘in range’.

“I’d rather not use VBA if possible” – but might be advisable!

However, use of some fixed references ($) should make it a little easier than otherwise with standard formulae only because the given discrete ranges (which may be appended in `ColumnA`) can be queried for various search values by copying the formulae across to the right/down as required and entering (as *Number* format) further search values in `Row1`.